# ArrayList constructor undefined when using nCopes(int, generic)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have the following class:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

and this is the constructor am using:

```
    Node(T data, int h) {
        this.tower = new ArrayList<Node<T>>(Collections.nCopies(h, data));
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Why is it giving me the following error:

```
The constructor ArrayList<Node<T>>(Collections.nCopies(h, data)) is undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You are building an `ArrayList` that is meant to contain `Node<T>` but you are supplying to the constructor a `List<T>` (and not `List<Node<T>>`), you probably want

```
Node(T data, int h) {
    this.tower = new ArrayList<Node<T>>(Collections.nCopies(h, new Node<T>(data)));
    this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: @vzdiegocm you're welcome, feel free to mark it as supposed answer

Answer (score 0):

Collections.nCopies is probably not what you want, as it will not actually create copies of the object itself, but only of the reference to it. Which means, changing the value of one of these nodes changes all, which is likely not what you want. If it isn't, then here's your solution:

```
Node(T data, int h) {
    this.tower =
        IntStream.range(0, h)              // these two lines do
                 .mapToObj((ignore)->data) // what Collections.nCopies does

                 .map(Node::new) // but here we're creating unique objects
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.data = data;
}
```

This way, each node is a separate object, but they all have the same initial value.